# Chose alternate certificate on visual studio CTP

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, certificate, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am using the [Multi-Device Hybrid Apps extension](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/explore/cordova-vs) for Visual Studio 2013. How can I choose the certificate to use [when signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230260.aspx#Choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution soon after I posted.

```
Windows 8: A custom package.appxmanifest file can be placed in the res/cert/windows8 folder 
to override a number of settings. You can grab the generated version in the 
bld/Debug/platforms/windows8 folder after building Debug for the 
Windows Local, Simulator, or Device target
```

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-faq-vs.aspx